# Wire brackets blocking circuit brakers from tripping

Tags: electrical

[image]I set my oven to self clean. When it was complete it would not light up. I checked the breaker and found a wire bracket blocking the trip. This type of bracket was also on my other bigger appliance breakers....except my AC. . I am wondering if the bracket should have been removed when the breaker panel was operational. The panel was installed 18 months ago.

The bracket is show in the photo. It does not link the switches it acts as a block.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the breaker panel, showing the wire brackets?

Comment: Most modern breakers will trip even if the handle can’t move or is locked with a locking tab.  Please post a pic and/or the model number of your breaker panel.

Comment: George, please [take the tour](http://diy.stackexchange.com) to understand how to respond to answers.

Answer (score 1):

As Tyson pointed out modern breakers are "Trip Free" meaning they can trip even if their handles are locked on.

The "wire bracket" you refer to is a breaker handle lock that is used just to keep people from inadvertently turning a breaker on or off that you want to stay off or on.

I put one on my sump pump circuit. There should also be one on your smoke detector circuit.

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely you are describing a handle TIE BAR that makes two single pole breakers act as a 2 pole breaker. It is not "blocking" the breaker from tripping, it's the other way around. Usually only one side trips, then this is supposed to make both sides open. But at the very least, it forces you to reset BOTH sides to make it work again. So make sure you move BOTH breaker handles all the way to the fully OFF position, then you can move them both back to the ON position.

By the way, THESE are "legal" tie bars on breakers:
[image]

If yours looks like this, it is ILLEGAL / hackwork:
[image]